# Refinery CMS: Adding custom field to custom engine index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

i have generated a custom engine "Pianos" inside of refinery cms. On the index piano page, I'd like to display the content of a related custom field called "pianos_introduction_text".

What would be the correct way to generate and display this custom field?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our preference however is to create custom page parts in the normal pages section, rather than to use the copywriting engine.

Under the pages admin section you should see that a page has been added for pianos.
If you add a new page part (or even use an existing one), you can then retrieve and render it from the engine's index page like this:

```
<%= raw @page.content_for(:new_page_part) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, there was no pianos page in the pages section. I had to do "rake db:seed", to finally see an pianos#index page template under pages. However, your answer is the correct way to accomplish a new page part. Should have been more precise in my question. I mark that one as correct.